# Subeport values not changing dynamically in SSRS

Tags: sql, dynamic, reporting-services, parameters, subreport

I have a problem in my subreport.

SQL:

```
SELECT ID, Ethnicity, Year
from Table
where Year = @Year
and ID = @Id
```

I am using Ethnicity value in my report but when I select different Id's I get same Ethnicity.

I set Filters in my tablix to filter for Id which is selected.

Any idea or help on this is much appreciated.

Thanks,
Ark

Answer (score 1):

You have to put the filter in the dataset instead of the tablix. 
And the datas will be refresh when you'll click on the button after chossing parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of putting the Dataset reference in my report expression I used just the field and this resolved the issue.